# Designate system-allocated memory as uncollectable

Tags: c, libgc

I wish to put pointers allocated via `GC_MALLOC` in memory allocated with the standard `malloc()`. The manual says to not do this, but this memory is allocated in a library I do not have control over. Is it possible to designate the memory allocated by `malloc()` as uncollectable in the same way that `GC_MALLOC_UNCOLLECTABLE()` does for memory that it allocates? That is, so that it will know to scan that memory for pointers, but not attempt to free it.

The only alternative I can think of is to allocate some memory via `GC_MALLOC_UNCOLLECTABLE()` in addition to the `malloc`-allocated memory, just to place the pointer in both places, but I am hoping for a less awkward solution.